# Looking for a Complete, Preferably English (Latin OK), Public Domain Translation of Peter Lombard's "Four Books of Sentences"

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, translation

I am looking for a **public domain** English translation of all four volumes of Perter Lombard's *The Sentences*---"one of the least read of the world’s great books".

I am, however, not sure that such exists.

The earliest translation that I have found is by Giulio Silano, which came out roughly fifteen years ago. See, for example, [The Sentences Book 1: The Mystery of the Trinity (Mediaeval Sources in Translation)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0888442920).

If this is indeed the earliest such translation, then what I am looking for does not exist.

As for Latin, I have found [Petri Lombardi's
Libri IV Sententiarum](https://ia800502.us.archive.org/20/items/libriivsententia01pete/libriivsententia01pete.pdf), but it does not appear to contain all four books.

QUESTION: Does anyone know of a public domain English translation of all four volumes of Peter Lombard's, "The Sentences"? Or, is anyone reasonably certain that none exist? If no such English translation exists, is there a complete Latin translation to be found that was published in the last two hundred years or so? (i.e., not [Liber IV sententiarum (Four Books of Sentences)](https://archive.org/details/lewis_e_170/page/n5/mode/2up))

Comment: [book 4](https://archive.org/details/sentencesbook1my0000pete_k7w9/mode/2up)

Comment: @depperm Thank you. It seems that it is a limited preview with a purchase option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archive.org has all volumes from your link:

- [tomes 1 & 2](https://archive.org/details/libriivsententia01pete)
- [tomes 3 & 4](https://archive.org/details/libriivsententia02pete)

This edition isn't stamped with a © copyright logo:

- [***Sententiæ In IV Libris Distinctæ*** (3° ed.)](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DLombardi%2C%20magistri%20Petri%20(Parisiensis%20episcopi)%22)

Comment: Thank you very much for this post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably certain no public domain English (or Latin, though less sure about this as I'm unfamiliar with this language) translation of all four volumes exist.

[Franciscan Archive](https://www.franciscan-archive.org/lombardus/) has a version of book 1 (80$ for CD), but book 2 was due to release in 2010, and hasn't so is probably a dead end

[HS Augusburg](http://www.hs-augsburg.de/%7Eharsch/Chronologia/Lspost12/PetrusLombardus/pet_s103.html) contains some free text (but only some select text)

[Les Enluminuries](https://www.lesenluminures.com) says:

> The Sentences was the most important medieval textbook on theology. Surviving in numerous manuscripts, they are available only sporadically on the market (seven have changed hands in the last 30 years, some multiple times)<sup>1</sup>

Which hints at the rarity of said manuscripts and value (also wikipedia only lists one translation)

Potential partial documents:

<sub>A [digital scan](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/view/bsb10813126?page=1) document in Latin? on German? website (I believe this is one of the books or commentary)</sub>

<sub>A [digital scan](https://www.documentacatholicaomnia.eu/02m/1095-1160,_Petrus_Lombardus,_Sententiarum_Libri_Quatuor,_MLT.pdf) of Latin text</sub>

<sub>Lincoln's Cathedral Library contains MS 31, 230 but not digital<sup>2</sup></sub>

<sub>1 https://www.textmanuscripts.com/tm-assets/tm-descriptions/tm0772-description.pdf</sub>

<sub>2 https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/traditio/article/abs/an-early-version-of-peter-lombards-lectures-on-the-sentences/32069E4398E039BEFD48869BFC8000B6</sub>

Comment: +1 Thank you for providing this information.